# Moto Turbo Charger for Raspberry PI 3 Model B

Tags: power-supply

I have recently brought Raspberry PI 3 Model B, however still don't have power supply which give output as 5V and 2A min.

Moto Turbo Charger output read as

- Standard - 5V/2.85A
- Turbo1 -9V/2.85A
- Turbo2 -12V/2.15A

Is it safe to use this charger for power supply in Raspberry PI 3 Model B.

Here is [link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01884O0XW)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds perfectly fine to use for a Pi. The Pi 3's requirements [are](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#powerReqs) listed in the FAQ:

> The device is powered by 5V micro-USB.
>
> **Recommended PSU current capacity:** 2.5 A
>
> **Maximum total USB peripheral current draw**: 1.2 A
>
> **Typical bare-board active current consumption**: 400 mA

Using a 2.5 A supply is recommended by the Pi Foundation, and it appears that [one reviewer](https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R2N71RRXJMX77M/ref=cm_cr_getr_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B01884O0XW) tried it with a Pi:

> I also use one of these for my Raspberry Pi 3, because it can run 2.85A@5V, which is notably higher than other chargers, which seem to max out at 2.3-2.4A.

It sounds successful enough. It doesn't matter too much that the current rating is beyond the recommended, as current is only drawn through as required. Having a slightly higher rating (only 12% above the 2.5 A recommendation anyway) won't matter a lot.

Note that the turbo modes would not be appropriate, unless you like [*fried Pi*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lYf9HK-rI1s)!

<sup>No, seriously, using a 12 V supply will destroy your Pi. While it probably won't actually ignite (that was a 12 V lead-acid battery which probably supplied a lot more current), it certainly will be a paperweight after overloading it.</sup>

Fortunately, [a brief read of the technical documents](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NCP4371-D.PDF) (that's for Quick Charge, which is largely the same as turbopower; see the [marketing material for a reference](https://www.motorola.com/us/products/turbopower)) suggests that a device specifically has to negotiate for higher voltage; by default, it'll send just the normal 5 V of the USB standards.

Comment: I understand, 2.85 Amp is OK with PI 3. Are you saying it it safe to use this charger with PI 3 as it will provide 5v/2.85a and not 9v.

Comment: Yes, it says it supports 'most micro-USB devices', so 5 V devices are supported. I believe that devices have to specifically ask the charger to use a higher voltage; by default it'll be 5 V only. Double check the manual though to be sure if you do order this.